# SORT - what if there are missing values in some columns?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sorting

I want to use SORT command to sort a tabular file based on the 5th column, however, there are some missing values in the 3rd column. And I noticed that sort command does not work properly with -k5,5, but -k1,1 or -k2,2 has no problem. Is it because of the missing values?

Comment: Seems like it is somehow ignoring the extra whitespace, is the blank data critical or could you attempt to alter the table with some `sed`/`awk` magic and put blank values like `.` or `0` in the space and see if it allows `-k5,5` to work?

Comment: If by "missing" you mean "empty", sort cannot determine that: it will just see four columns.

Comment: I meant "" by "missing", two continuous TABs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `sort` believes that a field begins whenever there's a whitespace character followed by a non-whitespace character. For example, in this snippet:

```
a     b     c     d
e           f     g
```

the first line has four fields, and the second line has three fields.

If you want to use a different separator, you can specify that by using the `-t` option. For example, to use tabs as separators, you can write:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 5,5
```

That will let `sort` detect empty fields (because two consecutive tabs will be interpreted as two different separators, with an empty field between them).

Comment: one more question: why do you use $'\t' here? can I use "\t" here? what is the difference?

Comment: Double quoted strings in bash do not interpret escape sequences specially. `"\t"` is just a 2-character string containing a backslash and a letter t. Documentation at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Answer (score 0):

If you are sometimes missing columns, I'm going to guess that your data is fixed format, that is, textually aligned like this:

```
1  2       3
2 23   12345
```

or this

```
1  2   3
2  23  12345
```

rather than this

```
1 2 3
2 23 12345
```

And if that's true, you can use a tab character that doesn't actually appear in the input and sort the now single-field with a key like `-t/ -k1.20` to sort on characters beginning at column 20.